# Import account list into sugarcrm by using other key field instead of record IDs

Tags: import, sugarcrm

When I want to import Accounts csv to sugarcrm. it will check the import file containing values that match the IDs of existing records will not be imported if the values are mapped to the ID field.
Possible not to use record IDs instead of some other column/field?

Is that only way modify it in logic hook file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the concepts here to adjust the SugarCRM import to do its id-matching to any field. The author uses email address but I've used the same idea to match off of phone numbers and other ID fields.

[SugarCRM Import: Update by Email Address](http://www.eggsurplus.com/content/import-update-by-email-address)

Comment: Thank you so much for the link attached!